# Is function $f$ convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

$$f(x) = (x_1-x_2)^2+\frac{1}{1+x_1^2+x_2^2}$$

Is $f$ convex? And why? Also, is $(1,-1)$ a local/global minimum?

Comment: What are $x, x_1, x_2$? Did you try inserting the definition of a convex function? Did you tried the standard way to find out if a function attains a minimum / maximum?

Comment: Restrict $f$ on the line $x_1=x_2$. You see, $f$ isn't convex!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Here is what the function looks like near $(0,0)$. It is neither convex nor concave and $1$ is a local minimum

Now to prove that we compute at $(0,0)$ after the change of variable

$$\begin{align}
X=&{x_1+x_2\over\sqrt{2}}\\
Y=&{x_1-x_2\over\sqrt{2}}
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
{\partial^2{f}\over\partial{X^2}} & {\partial^2{f}\over\partial{X}\partial{Y}}\\
{\partial^2{f}\over\partial{Y}\partial{X}} & {\partial^2{f}\over\partial{Y^2}}
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0\\
0 & 3
\end{bmatrix}$$

And we have our conclusion